# Linking 2 forms using ID

Tags: microsoft-access, forms

I am creating a database for customer laybyes and deposits. I have a form called active list, what I am trying to achieve is to link the active list form with other forms containing Laybye details and another one containing Deposit details of a particular customer . I was wondering if there is a code that I could use to link them, using ID perhaps.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use the same technique I just explained to someone here a few minutes ago:

https://superuser.com/a/1643397/1060127